# eclipseでデバッグすると実行できずに、LayoutInflater.classのタブが表示される。

Tags: eclipse, google-maps

eclipseを使い、Googleマップを使ったプログラムを作っていたのですが、ある時地図の表示が出来なくなりました。
代わりに
[image: LI1]
のタブが表示されます。

LocCatは
[image: lilog1]
[image: lilog2]
[image: lilog3]
[image: lilog4]
このような感じでした。

原因はなんなのでしょうか？教えていただければと思います。

**追記**
argiusさんこの画面のことでしょうか？
[image: console]

**追記2**
quesera2さん、argiusさんアドバイスありがとうございます。
argiusさんに張っていただいたリンクでやっているのは[「Google Maps Android API v2 を利用するための Google Play Services API ライブラリの参照」](http://android.keicode.com/basics/mapview-v2-reference-google-play-services.php)と同じですよね。だとするとコードに問題があるのでしょうか？

**追記3**
ただマップを表示させるだけの短いコードで確認しながら、新しいプロジェクトを作ってみたのですがやっぱりうまくいきません。数日前までは同じ環境で動いていたのですが…

Comment: Debugビューに`NoClassFoundError`が表示されているので、何かクラスが見つからないのでしょう。

実行ボタン（再生ボタンのような緑色のボタン）を押して処理続行して、エラーのスタックトレースを出力させ、どのクラスが見つからないのかを特定してみてください。

Comment: エラーログを普通にテキストで貼り付けた方が見やすいかと思います。原因は`java.lang.noclassdeffounderror: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable`ですね。Google Play Servicesの導入手順を再度確認してみてください。

Comment: その画面です。下記のページなどを参考にすれば解決するかもしれません。それ以外の場合でも完全クラス名でググれば何か見つかると思いますよ。
[開発メモ Android google mapでjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable](http://daiisop0123.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-7.html)

Comment: 情報が不足しているため、「何が」間違っているのか断定できませんが、導入方法が根本的に間違っているのだと思います。[Google Maps Android API v2のGetting Started](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#installing_the_google_maps_android_v2_api)と[Setting Up Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html)を参照に、もう一度導入方法を見直してみてください。